# Information from ICEcast

Tags: javascript, php, html, icecast, internet-radio

I have a Dutch Radio Station called FinioxFM and I would like to get information from my ICEcast server to my website. I'm using Airtime, I've searched all over the internet and I couldn't find a answer. I saw a lot op options but they were all from 2007 or 2010 and I didn't know if they would still work now. My question is how do I get this information from my ICEcast server. Or is there a simple way with Airtime? Do I use HTML, Java Script or PHP? What are my options?

Using Airtime V2.5.1 and a direct link to my stream is http://radio.finiox.com:8000/live - My website is http://www.finiox.com

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: If you don't want to connect to the server directly, I have an API available that will pull the metadata directly out of the stream and return as JSON.  http://api.audiopump.co/metadata/getStreamMetadata?url=http%3A%2F%2Fradio.finiox.com%3A8000%2Flive&apiKey=UB1z5zhLThZ4pBnhBUyPQjSGLSGpgvK6  You can get a free API key here:  http://audiopump.co/accounts/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a rather old version of Icecast, that leads to three options:

1. Upgrade to latest version (2.4.1) and use the JSON API. (Official packages for many distributions available at http://icecast.org/download/)
2. Retrofit the JSON API files (status-json.xsl and xml2json.xslt) and put them in your webroot
3. Write custom XSLT and access that. Some old examples are here: http://ruecker.fi/foss/icecast/xslt/

Please note that both option 2 and 3 mean that you need to do the query and inclusion on the server side. While on Icecast 2.4.1 or newer you also query that data directly from the client web browser, as Icecast supports sending CORS ACAO headers. (See default config and documentation)